# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process'

Tags: webpack

Estoy usando nativescript+Angular para hacer una App, y al momento de ejecutar tns run android, me da el siguiente error:

```
D:\wk-app>tns run android
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: e24b8ec0a7d0cf7f450e
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 12491ms
Built at: 2020-02-13 15:59:44
 3 assets
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 4.06 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app-routing.module.ts] 1.33 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.html] 187 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 379 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 3.12 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/guards/auth.guards.ts] 1.88 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/models/user.model.ts] 352 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/auth.service.ts] 1.01 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/feathers.service.ts] 2.03 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/user.service.ts] 966 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/utility.service.ts] 1.46 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/stores/login.store.ts] 2.73 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./environments/environment.ts] 702 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 2.34 KiB {bundle} [built]
    + 856 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'D:\wk-app\src\node_modules\xmlhttprequest-ssl\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js 16:12-36
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/transports/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/socket.js
 @ ./node_modules/engine.io-client/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js
 @ ./node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/index.js
 @ ./app/services/feathers.service.ts
 @ ./app/app.module.ts
 @ ./main.ts
```

package.json

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.workingreatapp",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.3.1"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.3.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@feathersjs/authentication-client": "^4.5.1",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
    "angularx-social-login": "^2.2.1",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "~8.20.3",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.4",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "xmlhttprequest-ssl": "^1.6.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^9.0.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  },
  "gitHead": "fa98f785df3fba482e5e2a0c76f4be1fa6dc7a14",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application"
}
```

Comment: El módulo no está en el directorio correcto

Comment: @Erick en que directorio debería de estar ?, actualmente esta en node_modules

Comment: Te dejo el link que te puede servir https://lifesaver.codes/answer/import-d3-causes-webpack-dependency-errors